# WebStorm eslint-config-standard error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webstorm, eslint

I'm using WebStorm IDE to create a Node.js server.

I installed [eslint-config-standard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-standard) as instructed by running:

`npm install --save-dev eslint-config-standard eslint-plugin-standard eslint-plugin-promise eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-node`.

I set the ESLint package in WebStorm setting but I still get a warning as seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run eslint-config-standard directly. You need installing eslint (`npm install eslint --save-dev`) in your project and specify `path/to/project/node_modules/eslint` as **ESLint package:** value.

BTW, WebStorm also supports [standard](https://standardjs.com/#usage) - see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2272/ for details